# Why isn't C++ being detected in VSCode as a language? Instead, it is being detected as a text file

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

I have installed C/C++ according to [vscode-doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) in my windows machine. Everything is okay but when I am creating C/C++ file , it isn't detecting. **Even I can't see C/C++ option in 'select language mode option'.**

Other code editor is fine with this compiler.

[vscode c++ file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nyDK.png)

[GCC version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu7gl.png)

I have tried [vscode-doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) step by step. But still not working.
(use cpp extension too)

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of language selector, where if you search "C++" it doesn't show up?

Comment: do you see the C/C++ extension listed when you run the command to show running extensions in the command palette?